# Link & useHistory.push from 'react-router-dom' changes URL but Not reloading page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to have a button to redirect to homepage on `404` and `errorBoundary` pages.

I am getting history object and url changes on button click.
However, it does not reload homepage.

Link & useHistory works perfectly on other pages except these two !

tried Router & BrowserRouter both from 'react-router-dom', but none of them worked.

Any advice ? Thank you !!

**versions**

```
react 17.0.2
react-dom 17.0.2
react-router-dom 5.2.0
```

**routes.js**

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const routes = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                <App />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path={['/', '/reserves']} component={ReservesMain} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/reserve/:id" component={ReserveMain} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/managers" component={ManagersMain} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/manager/:id" component={ManagerMain} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
  </Router>
);
```

**notFound.js**

```
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '../components/shared/button';

...

export default function NotFound() {
    const history = useHistory();

    const onRedirect = () => history.push('/');

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>404. Not Found. </h1>
            <p>Oops! Something's missing...</p>
            <p>The page does not exist or is unavailable.</p>
            <Link to={'/'}>redirect button</Link>
            <Button name="Go Home" onClick={onRedirect} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**errorBoundary.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '../components/shared/button';

const BadRequest = ({ status }) => [
    <h1 key="be-1">
        {status ? <span>{status}.</span> : null} This page isn't working.
    </h1>,
    <h2 key="be-2">Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>,
    <h2 key="be-3">If the problem continues, contact the engineer department.</h2>,
];

const SystemError = ({ status }) => [
    <h1 key="se-1">
        {status ? <span>{status}.</span> : null} Something went wrong.
    </h1>,
    <h2 key="se-2">Oops! We're experiencing an internal Server Error.</h2>,
    <h2 key="se-3">Please try again later.</h2>,
];

export const ErrorComponents = ({ status }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    
    const onRedirect = () => history.push('/');

    return (
        <>
            <div style={rootStyle}>
                <div style={innerStyles}>
                        {status === 400 ? <BadRequest status={status} /> : <SystemError status={status} />}
                    <Button name="Go Home" onClick={onRedirect} />
                </div>
        </>
    );
};

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        return { error };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            console.log(`error : ${error.name}, message: ${error.message || 'null'}`);
            console.log(`info : ${JSON.stringify(info)}`);
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
            return <ErrorComponents status={this.props.asyncApi.status} />;
        }

        return this.props.children;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    asyncApi: state.asyncApi,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ErrorBoundary);
```

Comment: try by downgrading the react-router-dom version to 4.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Yushan. Downgrading the version didn't work out for me though !

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a https://codesandbox.io?